# Possible to create a new sObject with Tooling API REST interface?

Tags: tooling-api

By my reading of the docs, it should be possible to create a new SObject by POSTing to `/tooling/SObjects/EntityDefinition`, but I haven't made it work.  Here's an example (the result of some trial-and-error, not all of which I have a record of), which I POSTed to `/services/data/v34.0/tooling/sobjects/EntityDefinition`:

```
{
    "Fullname" : "New_Object__c",
    "Metadata" : { 
        "label" : "New Object",
        "pluralLabel" : "New Objects"
    }
}
```

This returns the error:

```
[ {
  "message" : "Must specify a nameField of type Text or AutoNumber",
  "errorCode" : "FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION",
  "fields" : [ ]
} ]
```

So then I tried:

```
{
    "Fullname" : "New_Object__c",
    "Metadata" : { 
        "label" : "New Object",
        "pluralLabel" : "New Objects"
    },
    "nameField" : {
             "DeveloperName" : "name", 
             "DataType" : "AutoNumber" 
     }
}
```

which returns the error:

```
[ {
  "message" : "No such column 'nameField' on sobject of type EntityDefinition",
  "errorCode" : "INVALID_FIELD"
} ]
```

Is it possible to create an SObject in this manner?  I'd rather use Tooling API than Metadata API, as I'd like to stick to using REST.

**Update:** per the suggestion, I've moved nameField into the metadata hash like so:

```
{
    "Fullname": "New_sObject__c",
    "Metadata": {
        "label": "New Object",
        "pluralLabel": "New_Objects",
        "sharingModel": "ReadWrite",
        "deploymentStatus": "Deployed",
        "nameField": {
            "label": "qwerty",
            "type": "Text",
            "fullName": "asdfgh"
        }
    }
}
```

Which results in:

```
[ {
  "message" : "insufficient access rights on cross-reference id",
  "errorCode" : "INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY",
  "fields" : [ ]
} ]
```

Confusing, as I'm not referencing any ids.  I also tried `"fullName" : "name"` thinking that might be required.

Comment: What place in the documentation makes you think that you can create a new SObject by sending POST to /tooling/SObjects/EntityDefinition? As far as I can see the only place where /sobjects/SObjectName/ mentions POST is where POST used to create ApexExecutionOverlayAction.

Comment: Well, good point; it's not explicitly listed as a use case.  However, ApexExecutionOverlayAction seemed to be an example; I had hoped I could post to any sObject; also, comments I heard this week during a DF15 session (API Evolution session on Wed at 3pm, I think) led me to believe that the new Object Manager in Lightning Experience(!) was using the Tooling API , and EntityDefinition was called out specifically.

Comment: EntityDefinition's own describe reports that it is createable: false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Current version (v34) of `/tooling/sobjects` works with Tooling API SObjects (e.g.MetadataContainer). 
You can use to it to create **records** of **existing** Tooling API Sobject types, **not** new custom object types (e.g. `New_sObject__c`) as in your example.

This is similar to how you can use normal ([/xx.x/sobjects/SObjectName/](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_sobject_basic_info.htm)) REST API endpoint to create new records of **existing** (non tooling API) objects.

Presently you can not use Tooling to create new arbitrary custom object (type). To create new SObject type(s) use Metadata API.

Answer (score 0):

```
I believe the namefield should be inside Metadata.



     {
    "Fullname": "New_sObject__c",
    "Metadata": {
        "label": "New Object",
        "pluralLabel": "New_Objects",
        "sharingModel": "ReadWrite",
        "deploymentStatus": "Deployed",
        "nameField": {
            "label": "qwerty",
            "type": "Text",
            "fullName": "asdfgh"
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Christian and gaisor are right. At this moment it is not possible to create objects via rest API as the Metadata rest API was put on hold.

The error you are getting is because you are trying to do something that is not supposed to be done like creating an entity which has creatable as false.

Comment: Thanks Manjit; while it seems happy to have nameField moved into the metadata hash (and I'd love to know where that is documented), I'm still not able to create the object; see the additional information I've added to the original question for details.