# Delete the Selected sObject or field from Org using apex

Tags: apex

1. How to delete sObject (ex. account or Custom__c) from Org. using apex code.
2. How to identify the objects and fields is deletable using apex.
3. How to Create new object and field using apex code.

Comment: You cannot change object and field definitions in Apex unless you use a library like [apex-mdapi](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) to talk to the Metadata API.

Comment: Hello Deepak, Welcome to SFSE. What attempts have you made to solve these questions. Where are you stuck?

Comment: You'll never be able to delete the `Account` object no matter what you do (nor any other standard object).

Comment: @RedDevil, actually I want to take a backup of the object with filter criteria as well as delete the selected object and its selected fields. The data should be stored in 3rd party database.

Answer (score 2):

Well Basically there are two ways to do this.

1. Using MetaData API: Apex-MDapi is an excellent API built on top of Salesforce Native Metadata API that allows you to create and delete objects.
   SRC: https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi

   ```
   public static void createObject() {
    MetadataService.MetadataPort service = createService();
   MetadataService.CustomObject customObject = new 
   MetadataService.CustomObject();
   customObject.fullName = 'Test__c';
   customObject.label = 'Test';
   customObject.pluralLabel = 'Tests';
   customObject.nameField = new MetadataService.CustomField();
   customObject.nameField.type_x = 'Text';
   customObject.nameField.label = 'Test Record';
   customObject.deploymentStatus = 'Deployed';
   customObject.sharingModel = 'ReadWrite';
   List < MetadataService.SaveResult > results =
   service.createMetadata(
    new MetadataService.Metadata[] {
     customObject
    });
    handleSaveResults(results[0]);
   }
   ```
2. Using Tooling API: Tooling API from Salesforce allows you to create and update objects using beautiful REST API.
   SRC: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_customobject.htm

   [Possible to create a new sObject with Tooling API REST interface?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/92987/possible-to-create-a-new-sobject-with-tooling-api-rest-interface)

   Limitations: you cannot Use Tooling API in live. :(