# Can a new SObject type or new SObject field be created via the Tooling API?

Tags: tooling-api, sobjecttype, sobjectfield

The [Tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_api_tooling.htm) is great - very easy to use from Apex code by making HTTP calls containing straightforward JSON.

Two questions:

1. Is it still **not** possible to create a new SObject type e.g. `MyNewCustomType__c`?

   - see [Possible to create a new sObject with Tooling API REST interface?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/92987/possible-to-create-a-new-sobject-with-tooling-api-rest-interface)
   - the [CustomObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_customobject.htm) documentation does not list POST
2. Can a custom field be added to an already existing SObject type?

   - the [CustomField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_customfield.htm) documentation lists POST that makes me think the answer is "yes"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You still cannot create Custom Object with REST API, only with METADATA API.
2. Yes, you can create a Custom Field on existing sObject, request example:

```
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
request.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/v41.0/tooling/sobjects/CustomField/');
request.setMethod('POST');

String fieldLabel = 'New_Label';
String objectAPIName = 'Account';
String fieldAPIName = fieldLabel + '__c';

request.setBody('{"Metadata" : {"type" : "Text","description" : "", "inlineHelpText" : "","precision" : null,"label":"' + fieldLabel + '","length" : 255,"required" : false}, "FullName" : "'+objectAPIName+'.'+fieldAPIName+'"}');

Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(request);
system.debug(res.getBody());
```

Comment: That's helpful - thank-you. In fact I want to create a fake object as part of the CI build, so given your answer, I'll use `sfdx force:source:deploy` of a separate folder containing the object definition instead.